# My <div> choses max-width between "min-width" "max-width"

Tags: blogs, blogger, css

I have a blog and I want to have 2 posts per line. To do that I've tried this:

`.post { float:left;
width:45%;}`

Well that worked, I have 2 posts floated to the left and they are in the same line.

But, when I enter in the post I want the width of the post to be bigger, but it has the same width as before, something that now I don't want. So I thought to do something like:

`.post { float:left; min-width:45%;
 max-width:90%; width:auto ;}`

But now for the width turns to chose always the `max-width`.

How will I give priority to the `min-width`, and only if there is enough space, to the `max-width`?

Comment: Take the width=auto out of your CSS.

Comment: When i do that, the post's width becomes the "max-width".

Answer (score 0):

You should perhaps place the post elements into a holding div, and give that dive a specific size. The holding div will always be the maximum size.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer. But i don't think that i want that. What i need is a way to make it chose the "min-width" instead the "max-width".
Thanks again for the response!

Comment: Then you should just set the width normally:

.post { float:left; width:45%; min-width:45%; max-width:90%;}

Comment: Thanks again for the response. Well i tried that and it didn't worked. When I am on the home page where i see all the posts, it  works (I see 2 posts per line), BUT when I enter in a post the width is the same because we have set it that way "width:45%". We have to think out of the box. 
Thanks for your time